# Automatically update a column at a special date

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I have a table with malty columns, and I use CodeFirst.

```
     public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

     public DateTime DateOfArchive { get; set; }
```

I want to  edit automatically `IsArchived` to True when `DateOfArchive >= Today`, and don't want to set it manually.

Is there any way for update record automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in the constructor of the entity :

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        //this.IsArchived=(DateOfArchive>DateTime.Today)? false:true;
        if (DateOfArchive >= DateTime.Today)
            this.IsArchived = true;
        else
            this.IsArchived = false;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfArchive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to edit `IsArchive` when `DateOfArchive>=Today` , no set it in add.

Comment: what do you mean? you can set `Ture` or `False` in `IsArchive`

Comment: I add a record on table then i want edit automatically my record when `DateOfArchive>=Today` , I use job for edit record in sql server, but when i use code first and EntityFramework , I do not know how to do it!